# Remove entry from comma separated list in a column

Tags: sql

I have one table in which I have a tag column with comma separated list:

```
    ## Tag ###

A
ABC,AB
Abc,A,Ab
```

I want to remove only 'A' Tag from table.

Comment: As per my understanding 'Abc,A,Ab' will have output as 'Abc,Ab'..But what will happen cell has value only 'A'.. will it become blanks???

Comment: Yes....It Should Be Blank....

Comment: This is why you should normalize your data.

Comment: Cilent Want to Remove these tag from Sysytem

Comment: This will require string manipulation. Since each RDBMS has slightly different string functions, you should specify which database you are using. But as @EdCottrell pointed out, It is a mistake to store the data this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this query on your test database, It should work.I am assuming #test is your table and [value] is the column.

```
update #test
set value=  replace(','+value+',',',A,',',')

update #test
set value= case when len(value)=0 then '' else STUFF(value, 1, 1, '')  end 

update #test
set value=  case when len(value)=0 then '' else  STUFF(value, len(value),1, '') end
```

Comment: Good to see it is working for you @Dipak Bilade..If is is working then you can accept as a answer or can wait for more better answer.